# How to debug an erlang application that won't boot

Tags: debugging, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

If i write some erlang code to build a supervision tree and then launch the application at the boot whith the following command, it may be very hard to find out why it doesn't work :

```
erl -s myapp -pa ebin ... ...
```

(myapp example module)

```
-module(myapp).
-export([start/0]).
start() -> application:start(myapp).
```

Let's say that my app launches a supervisor, myapp_sup. myapp_sup launches at its turn several supervisors (let's say server_sup, database_sup, another_sup).

Theese supervisors will launch some gen_servers.

At some point, if there is a mistake in my code, i cannot find it out !

I wrote a call to somemodule:functionthatdoesntexists() in the init callback of some gen_server.

All the vm says is "init terminating in do boot" and then display error location of a badmatch, precising file and line of my top module (myapp).

(Badmatch because ok = application:start(...) will not match).

I look in th erl_crash.dump file, and there is no information about this undefined function (yet i find it in the atoms list).

So, i wrote some log to see approximatively where is the error, but then i'll have to launch my gen_servers by the hand to get back the correct error information.

What am i missing, how could i figure it out faster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application makes a call to an unknown module, your `erl_crash.dump` file will contain a line like this one:

```
41DABB8:t4:A8:nonexistent_module,A7:unknown,N,N
```

where the "unknown" in the line indicates that the module `nonexistent_module` can't be found. Searching your `erl_crash.dump` file for the string "unknown" can help in these cases.

If you suspect a certain module makes a call to a function that doesn't exist, you can find it using [the xref tool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html) in an interactive erl shell. Make sure you compile the module with debug information (typically via `erlc +debug_info`), then:

```
1> xref:m(my_module).
[{deprecated,[]},
 {undefined,[{{my_module,init,1},{another_module,unknown,0}}]},
 {unused,[]}]
```

Here, `xref` shows us that the `my_module:init/1` function makes a call to the `another_module:unknown/0` function, but the `unknown/0` function isn't defined in `another_module`.

You can also use `xref` to check entire applications; see [the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html) for details

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But i do not have the same output as you. Neither for a non-existing module nor a non-exisiting function in an actual module.

I've added xref to my makefile, it's easy with rebar, thanks.

But the problem remains, let's say that i've mispelled the port on to which the database listen for example ... The problem is that you don't know what is the error you are lookig for most of the time.

Comment: The output I show above was obtained using Erlang/OTP R15B03 (erts 5.9.3.1); perhaps your version is different.

Comment: You should also consider implementing unit tests for your modules, as they can be quite good at catching problems like misspelled atoms or other names.

Comment: Same version, different config i suppose. You're right, i really should go for TDD. I'm not used to it in Erlang, i'll give this a try.

Comment: i develop a small application theese days, i've started with eunit. During tests, instead of fail whith obscure messages, Eunit gives me the exact line of code where errors occur. That's really nice. so thank again.

Answer (score 2):

Add -init_debug to your erl command :)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem : errors that come from user code doesn't happen in boot sequence. They come after. With '-init_debug' there is no more information about my undef function.